# How do I load a Metacello baseline from disk in cmd

Tags: git, pharo, metacello

I am using Pharo 6.1 64bits and Ubuntu 16 LTS.

How do I load a Tonel formated Baseline located at disk? I tried inside /home/vitormcruz/testpharo/:

```
./pharo Pharo.image eval "Metacello new baseline: 'Employees'; repository: 'filetree://employees/pharo'; load: #(core)"
```

But then I got:

```
Could not resolve: BaselineOfEmployees [BaselineOfEmployees] in /home/vitormcruz/testpharo/pharo-local/package-cache filetree:///home/vitormcruz/testpharo/employees/pharo
```

And ls -la of /home/vitormcruz/testpharo/employees/pharo gives:

```
drwxrwxr-x 4 vitormcruz vitormcruz 4096 Nov 12 16:21 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 vitormcruz vitormcruz 4096 Nov 12 15:57 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vitormcruz vitormcruz 69 Nov 12 16:21 .filetree
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vitormcruz vitormcruz 21 Nov 12 15:57 .properties
drwxrwxr-x 2 vitormcruz vitormcruz 4096 Nov 12 15:57 BaselineOfEmployees
drwxrwxr-x 2 vitormcruz vitormcruz 4096 Nov 12 15:57 Employees
```

It is strange that it tried to access the local cache, is that correct?

If I use gitlocal:// instead of filetree:// it can find the baseline class as long as the the .git folder is present (which shouldn't be necessary...), but Metacello is unable to load remote dependencies defined on the BaselineOf class failing with a `ZnTooManyRedirects`

Comment: Can you try using an absolute path to your project instead of a relative path? Because I use the same kind of command and it is working for me.

Comment: I think you have a problem with your export because Filetree package export creates folder ending with `.package`. So you should not have `BaselineOfEmployees` but `BaselineOfEmployees.package` in the ls output.

Comment: Well, I made it work using tonel format. I had a myriad of problems with baselines which I managed to fix by reading through this guide: https://github.com/pharo-open-documentation/pharo-wiki/blob/master/General/Baselines.md